# How to use a large Hadoop cluster to learn

Tags: hadoop

As we all know, the big difficulty in learning big data is that it is difficult to access large-scale data volume and machines, and only the principle can be learned through local virtual machines. Now I have access to a cluster of more than one thousand. How to make reasonable use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue the opposite. The point of massive distributed processing engines like Spark, Flink, etc. is that the code you write to process data will work for datasets of arbitrary size. You can do it on a VM or your laptop with 100 records and it will work more or less the same as if you processed 100 billion records on your 1,000 node cluster, assuming your input can be easily parallelized and isn't too badly skewed. I'm not sure why you have that many machines available to you without a clear goal, but there are tons of publicly available data sets that you can tinker with.